# tabularray, does exist equivalent for cell{<row>}{<columns>} in form \SetCell?

Tags: tabularray

Please, consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             cell{1}{2-4} = {bg=gray9}
            }
1 & Beta & Gamma & Delta    \\
2 & Beta & Gamma & Delta    \\
3 & \SetCell[c=2]{bg=red8}
    Beta & Gamma & Delta    \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

which produce

[image]

*Question*:
does exist settings for `\SetCell` (used in the third row) equivalent to `cell{3}{2-3} = {bg=red8}` used in `tblr` options? I like to get the same result with use of one  `\SetCell`.

Comment: I don't think that is possible since `\SetCell` locks the indices `i` and `j` to whereever the command is called. Maybe `\SetRow` accepts an optional argument to specify only certain columns?

Comment: @marv, I wonder about is. In manula on page 17 is noted " In fact, table command \SetCell[<span>]{<styles>} at the beginning of cell at row i and column
j is the same as table option cell{i}{j}={<span>}{<styles>}.
Also, table command \SetCells[<span>]{<styles>} at the beginning of some cell is the same as
table option cells={<span>}{<styles>}." , so I hope that this is somhow possible or what is more like that I mussunderstand this statement :-(

Comment: yeah, i also looked at this paragraph. Don't really understand the `<span>` argument of `\SetCells` (or `cells`). It doesn't make sense to set e.g. `c=2` for every cell. Also using this option e.g. with `cells=[c=2]{bg=red8}` produces an error for me. Reading the code, the optional argument of `\SetCells`  (or `cells`) is just passed to every cell. I guess this works in principle, but it is not sensible to set the `<span>` parameters `c` and `r` globally for every cell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a function that can do this. It gives the same result as your code. As far as I can see there is no similar functionality in `tabularray` itself.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Usage: \SetCellRange[r=#rows,c=#cols]{style}. Default: r=1,c=1
\NewTableCommand \SetCellRange [2] []  
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l__tblr_row_span_num_tl { 1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l__tblr_col_span_num_tl { 1 }
  \keys_set:nn { tblr-cell-span } { #1 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { \value{rownum} + \l__tblr_row_span_num_tl - 1 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { \value{colnum} + \l__tblr_col_span_num_tl - 1 }
  \tblr_set_cell:nnnn { \value{rownum}-\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }
                      { \value{colnum}-\int_use:N \l_tmpb_int } { } { #2 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\SetTblrTracing{all}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines}
1 & \SetCellRange[c=3]{bg=gray9} Beta & Gamma & Delta    \\
2 & Beta & Gamma & Delta    \\
3 & \SetCell[c=2]{bg=red8}
    Beta & Gamma & Delta    \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test your suggestion at late evening, so faR +1 :-)

Comment: The `\SetTblrTracing{all}` is there only for debugging.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much again! Now I have only one wish: that package author include your solution to next package realize. and make note about `cell` and `\SetCell` on page 17 (version 2021Q) more clear (see my comment below question).

Comment: You can put a request on https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues

Comment: @Zarko Sorry, I am not going to add this command to the package. But I will update the documentation for `\SetCells` command.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to define a short command for this usage:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewTableCommand\SC{\SetCell{bg=red8}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             cell{1}{2-4} = {bg=gray9}
            }
1 & Beta & Gamma & Delta    \\
2 & Beta & Gamma & Delta    \\
3 & \SC Beta & \SC Gamma & Delta    \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a good way too. Thank you to remind me for this possibilities.